# Exchange Api returns "Set action is invalid for property." on update

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a rather simple Exchange Api application with one major issue; Required/Optional Attendees for appointments created from Outlook cannot be update. However appointments that are created from application can be fully updated on both ends.

{"Set action is invalid for property."}

Is the return that I get. 
Here is XML that is being returned:

```
<Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="6" Time="2015-07-05 10:41:38Z" Version="15.00.0847.030">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="201" MinorBuildNumber="17" Version="V2_46" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
            <m:MessageText>Set action is invalid for property.</m:MessageText>
            <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidPropertySet</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
            <m:MessageXml>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:OptionalAttendees" />
            </m:MessageXml>
            <m:Items />
          </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:UpdateItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

And yes, I do load them beforehand:

```
 Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service,
            new ItemId(meeting.MeetingId),
            new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, 
                AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees, 
                AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees,
                AppointmentSchema.AppointmentState));
```

Please help!!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess here, but I suspect that attendees can only be updated by the organizer.  Thus if your app authenticates with credentials other than the person who made the appointment, EWS will not allow this.  I have seen this with updating of the recurrence pattern, hence my guess about attendees.  If you can impersonate the organizer, that may work, however that type of permission might not always be available.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This makes sense, however I have an application that I wrote prior to this one and It freely updates both Required and Optional attendees. Code is exactly the same, so I must be missing something..